# What's the equivalent of Microsoft Access on the Mac?

Tags: macos, software-rec, database

I want to use a Microsoft Access 2007 database on my Mac. However, it appears that Office 2008 for Mac does not have an equivalent to Microsoft Access. I'm new the Mac so can anybody suggest a easy to use alternative to Microsoft Access, preferably something that can import/migrate the existing data.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

FileMaker Pro would be your best bet. It's powerful, easy to user and mature.

[image]

Check out their [website](http://www.filemaker.com/products/index.html?homepage=fmp_product_line).

Answer (score 4):

[OpenOffice.org Base](http://dba.openoffice.org/).  Its free and cross-platform (windows, mac, linux).

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what you need from a database, so it's hard to predict what product would work for you. I use [Bento](http://www.filemaker.com/products/bento/overview.html) and think it's pretty good.

Comment: I believe Bento and FM Pro are consumer-grade and pro-grade levels of the same core product.

Comment: I don't think so; they seem completely different. They're both made by the same company, though.

Comment: @Graham A. Scagnelli is correct: Bento is the consumer FileMaker Pro

Comment: Now discontinued.

Answer (score -1):

File Maker Pro is an incredibly expensive way to open Access files on a Mac! There are several other cheaper and easier ways to do so (although editing Access files is another matter). If you're just looking to import or migrate existing data, or a small amount of editing, one of these apps will do the job much quicker and at a fraction of the cost: http://machow2.com/microsoft-access-mac-open-databases

Comment: Can you expand your answer to include the relevant information from the link?